# How to frame a PairedHistogram and manipulate the frame ticks?

Tags: plotting

How can I `Frame` a `PairedHistogram` and manipulate the frame ticks? I want to specify and control the frame ticks in the paired histogram below.

```
spacez = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[11], 1000];
spacem = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[11], 1000];
PairedHistogram[spacez, spacem, {1, 11, 1}, PlotRange -> {{All, All}},
  ChartStyle -> {{Red, Blue}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thick, BarSpacing -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[Opacity[0.5]], BarOrigin -> "XAxis"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `PairedHistogram` constructs its own axes/ticks, overriding to some extent (and thereby interfereing with) the standard system approach.  I don't know why it does this.  `Ticks` seems to be able to be used to relabel the automatically generated ticks (an observation), but the option cannot be used as it can with, say, `Plot`.  Passing a function, for instance, has no effect.

However, one can use `Frame`.  Use the `Axes` options `Frame` on.  Then you can use [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html) to specify ticks.  I made a function `absSingleTick` to reverse the sign of ticks with negative coordinates.

```
SeedRandom[1];
spacez = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[11], 1000];
spacem = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[11], 1000];

absSingleTick[{a_, b_}] := {a, Abs[b]};
absSingleTick[t_] := t;

PairedHistogram[spacez, spacem, {1, 11, 1}, PlotRange -> {{All, All}},
  ChartStyle -> {{Red, Blue}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}, 
 BarSpacing -> 0, ColorFunction -> Function[Opacity[0.5]], 
 BarOrigin -> "XAxis",
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Purple, 
 FrameTicks -> {
   {absSingleTick /@ Charting`FindTicks[{1, 0}, {1, 0}][##] &, Automatic},
   {Charting`FindTicks[{1, 0}, {1, 0}][##] &, Automatic}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Michael. That works great for me.

Comment: Would that work for the first example of the PairedHistogram page? Can't try it right now, but I guess the split x-axis will cause problems.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You can remove the gap with `BarSpacing -> 0` as the OP does.  However, I'm finding that (any) ticks functions for the horizontal frame element generate error messages, when I try the above method on the first `PairedHistogram` example. :(  Bug?